# json server and angular 15

Tags: angular, json-server

I am trying run json server and angular app at a time. But it is running one at a time.
I'm using the following command:

```bash
npm run start-server
```

in package json file following are the settings

```json
"name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
   "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "start-server": "npx json-server --watch test.json",
    "test": "ng test"
```

It is running only json server not app.
and when i am trying ng serve command it is running only angular app.

Comment: Yes that's how it works. They are completely separate things. One is a local web server for your application, the other is a local API instance. Do them in two separate terminal windows. Or if you REALLY want to do it from a single command you could try `npm run start-server && ng serve`

Comment: I have tried npm run start-server && ng serve but it is giving error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask TELLING what the error is would help you actually get an answer.